# Serializing queryset to JSON is taking a lot of time. How can I debug this?

Tags: django, json, django-serializer

I am serializing Django model objects in batches of 10000 as json and sending them. I am using [DjangoFullSerializers](http://code.google.com/p/wadofstuff/wiki/DjangoFullSerializers) from wadofstuff to do this, as I also wanted a related field to be serialized along with my object. During peak server load, one batch is taking around 9-10 mins to finish. A fetch of 10000 objects of MySQL takes somewhere between 1-2 seconds. I am not sure what a serialize to JSON might be doing to take so much overhead. I have tried using simplejson (which doesn't give the option to serialize related fields), but time taken is still long enough. I am not sure but I think, wadofstuff uses simplejson behind the screen.
I wasn't able to configure cjson with Django, so couldn't test on that. But how could I configure optimally or improve the usage of current setup. Intuitively, I feel, once the data has been fetched into memory, converting 10000 objects to JSON shouldn't take this long.
I am attaching the profile dump taken using cProfile. Please have a look and suggest some pointers/tips/help.

Attachment: [cProfile Dump File](http://cl.ly/3R0m2P0l3e2h1A3u2v3H)

Thanks in advance.

Update 1: Also writing the code that I am using for testing. I am running this in shell.

```
import cProfile
from dashboard.models import *
from django.core import serializers
from datetime import datetime

start = end = None
def myfunc():
 global start, end
 start = datetime.now()
 us = UserPermission.objects.filter(username = 54).values_list('district_operated', flat=True)
 villages = list(Village.objects.filter(block__district__id__in = us))
 offset = 0
 limit = 10000
 screenings = Screening.objects.select_related('village').filter(village__in = villages).distinct().order_by("-id")[offset:limit]
 x = list(screenings)
 json_subcat = serializers.serialize("json", screenings, relations=('village',))
 end = datetime.now()


cProfile.runctx("myfunc()", globals(), locals(), 'dump.profile')
```

Comment: are you fetching with `select_related`? otherwise you have an extra query for each object.

Comment: Queryset serialization may take a long time because of query-related data which are pickled too. You may want to evaluate it to a list of objects first using `list(my_queryset)` if you need only the objects.

Comment: Yes I have made sure to do both. select_related in the queryset and calling list() before calling serialize.